# Flat UI Pro Can not add on Rails4.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-4.2, flatui

I can not add Flat UI Pro to rails4.2
i used[reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2kR.png) 
but i can not

**STEP1**

・Flat-UI-HTML-Developers-License.zip download on Desktop

・changed folder name to flat-ui-pro

・Locate the bower.json file that unzipped with the kit, and run the following from the same directory: bower install

1. cd
2. cd Desktop
3. cd flat-ui-pro
4. cd HTML
5. cd UI
6. cd Flat-UI-Pro-1.3.2
7. bower install

**STEP2**

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails', '~> 1.3.2.0.branch'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

> bundle update 
>   and
>   bundle install

**STEP3**

```
bin/rails generate flatuipro:install ~/Desktop/flat-ui-pro
rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

**STEP4**

```
rails generate flatuipro:demo
```

**STEP5**
`scaffolds.scss` delete

but...collapse layout

**flatuipro_demo/index**
[image]

correctly layout 
[image]

**Example Post scaffold**

**select box**

collapse layout

[image]

correctly layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

HTML

```
<select class="form-control select select-default">
  <optgroup label="Profile">
  <option value="0">My Profile</option>
  <option value="1">My Friends</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="System">
  <option value="2">Messages</option>
  <option value="3">My Settings</option>
  <option value="4">Logout</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.select').select2();        
});
```

I got it from the github issues

https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI-Pro-Support/issues/450